# Altering find and replace Google Sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have the following script, though I would like to change it to only find and replace on a specific sheet (Sheet4!A:AB).

How would I go about doing this:

```
function fandr() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r=s.getDataRange();
  var vlst=r.getValues();
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
  find="abc";
  repl="xyz";
  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
    a=vlst[i][j];
    if (a==find) vlst[i][j]=repl;
  }
 }
  r.setValues(vlst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that pnuts's comment is helpful for your situation. If you are still looking for your solution, how about this answer? You want to find and replace the values in `Sheet4!A:AB`. If my understanding is correct, I would like to propose 2 patterns. I think that there are several solution for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Pattern 1

This modification is a simple modification. It modified the range for retrieving values to `Sheet4!A:AB`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = ss.getRange("Sheet4!A:AB");
var vlst = r.getValues();
var i, j, a, find, repl;
find = "abc";
repl = "xyz";
for (var i = 0; i < vlst.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < vlst[i].length; j++) {
    a = vlst[i][j];
    if (a == find) vlst[i][j] = repl;
  }
}
r.setValues(vlst);
```

#### Pattern 2

In the case of pattern 1, the values retrieved by `getRange("Sheet4!A:AB")` includes the empty rows. By this, the search speed becomes slow. So in this pattern 2, the data range of "A1:AB" is retrieved using `getLastRow()`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
var r = s.getRange("A1:AB" + s.getLastRow());
var vlst = r.getValues();
var i, j, a, find, repl;
find = "abc";
repl = "xyz";
for (var i = 0; i < vlst.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < vlst[i].length; j++) {
    a = vlst[i][j];
    if (a == find) vlst[i][j] = repl;
  }
}
r.setValues(vlst);
```

#### References :

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getlastrow)

If I misunderstand what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.